# jQuery Slider is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on very simple jQuery Slider.

**[JS BIN CODE](http://jsbin.com/pexigesu/1/edit)**

If I have more than 2 LI elements, slide effect works smoothly. But for 2 LI elements(current code), by clicking on next it shows the jerk effect, however on click of previous link the slide effect works perfect. Any clue or solution would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put your code in your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, EDITed.

As I pointed in the comments the problem is that when you click on next, there is no fist element to switch to, so it switches to a blank element and then it appends the first element.

Detailed explanation:

Quite simple actually. Your script had 3 'active' slides. The current, the next and the previous.

If you have only 2 slides, well you have no next slide (due to the ordering method you use), so instead of switching to the next slide you switched to an empty space and then placed the second slide on it's position (the second slide appears after the animation ends thus it 'flickers').

Now what does the 'patch' do. Well basically, you'll understand it once you try your code without the patch and remove 'margin-left: -500px' from the slider wrap, but I'll explain it anyway.

Let's imagine that instead of a list you have a basic array with only 2 values. You have 2 options: Next which increases the index by 1 and and Previous which decreases it by one. Your initial slide has index 0, so if you increase the index you go to index 1, and if you decrease it you get index -1 which results in an empty slide which caused the flickering, which is how your script works if you remove the 'margin-left' from the `<ul>` element.

If you add the 'margin-left' it goes into inverted mode (next flickers, but previous doesn't).

What the patch does is detect if the anomaly is valid, and switch on/off the `margin-left` value.

Unfortunately, when you do that the slides also switch order, so a extra append is required to put things in order. If you remove the extra appends in the IFs you'll notice this event.

the patch values do the following:
 0 - no need to patch.
 1 - next function needs to be fixed before the next use.
 2 - prev function needs to be fixed before the next use.

And the IFs do the fixing.

It can be fixed by adding a dummy element in the beginning by placing the following code:

```
if($('.slider ul').length<3){
          $('.slider ul li:first-child').clone().appendTo('.slider ul');
    }
```

end then erase it when you click on next or previous.

EDIT2: A much more elegant and complete solution! Ver 2.0

Edit the next AND prev function to:

```
var patched = 0;
if($('.slider ul li').length==2){
  patched = 1;
}

var sliderWrap = $('.slider ul'),
            slideElem = $('.slider ul li'),
            slideCount = slideElem.length,
            slideWidth = $('.slider ul li').width(),
            slideHeight = $('.slider ul li').height(),
            sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

        $('.slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
        $('.slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
        $('.slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('.slider ul');

        var previous = function() {
            if(patched==2){
              sliderWrap.css('margin-left','-500px');
              $('.slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('.slider ul');
              patched=1;
            }
            sliderWrap.animate({
                left: + slideWidth
            }, 200, function () {
                $('.slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('.slider ul');
                sliderWrap.css('left', '');
            });
        };

        var next = function() {

            if(patched==1){
              sliderWrap.css('margin-left','0px');
              $('.slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('.slider ul');
              patched=2;
            }
            sliderWrap.animate({
                left: - slideWidth
            }, 200, function () {
                $('.slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('.slider ul');
                sliderWrap.css('left', '');
            });
        };
```

Try the new one: http://jsbin.com/pexigesu/32/edit

EDIT: To cover the case with 1 slider only, change the beginning to:

```
if($('.slider ul li').length==2){
  patched = 1;
}else if($('.slider ul li').length==1){
  $('.slider ul li:last-child').clone().prependTo('.slider ul');
  $('.slider ul li:last-child').clone().prependTo('.slider ul');
}
```

It simply clones the 1st element twice and since it's pretty much the same element, no control is required. [JSbin example](http://jsbin.com/pexigesu/38/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution makes the two code blocks do the same thing. I think the challenge here is how to get animation to work smoothly in both directions.

Comment: Agreed with E.Maggini. and I have already mentioned that for more than 2 LI the animation works perfectly.

Comment: just to add.. you need to place LI before animate

Comment: Yes, I know that his problem is that there is no li in the begining so it slides to an empty field and then refreshes it. Working on workaraound at the moment

Comment: The solution posted above still results in flashing.

http://jsbin.com/pexigesu/29/edit

Comment: This works. :) Now can you explain to us what the fix was? How does "patch" work?

Comment: @Hristo thank you so much for the effort. It is working. One bug, can you please also fix the case(one LI element only), currently it's not visible.

Comment: Edited, Check if it covers what you need. :)